# Label glitch when switching between Tab Bar View Controllers

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uiviewanimation

I have created an animated label with UIView that is glitches when switching between View Controllers within a Tab Bar.

I've attached a GIF of what's occurring and a picture of my storyboard layout below, respectively.

[Glitching Label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T0PcL.gif)

[Storyboard Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3tY7.png)

*Caveat:* I realize that my code is not-so-elegant, to put it nicely, but does anyone know why this is happening or how I can

A) stop this from happening?

***and/or***

B) fix it?

Is it my code (probably), a bug within the simulator (not likely), or am I approaching the animation incorrectly?

I'm using this

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(true)

    self.updateGSLabel(textArray: ["Game Mode", "Play"], index : 0)
}

func updateGSLabel(textArray : [String], index : Int){

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.25, animations: {
        self.gameModeLabel.alpha = 0.0
    }) { (success) in
        self.gameModeLabel.text = textArray[index]
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.25, animations: {
                self.gameModeLabel.alpha = 1.0
            }) { (success) in

                var  newIndex = index

                if(newIndex == textArray.count - 1) {
                    newIndex = -1
                }
                self.updateGSLabel(textArray: textArray, index : newIndex + 1)

        }
    }
}
```

***EDIT***

This may have something to do with closure parameters, but I don't know. If someone could elaborate better that'd be appreciated.

I tried to link to a page about it, but apparently I need at least 10 rep to post more than 2 links, which I think I've already done so I don't know how that's possible.

Comment: I'll give that a shot @harshalvalanda

Comment: post that as an answer and I'll accept; a tiny explanation why that works would be great but I think I get why and can research. @harshalvalanda